# Full width of singular item within a flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a responsive design, I really don't want to change the HTML markup but rather make what I have work.

I have a container with three elements (a category, an image thumbnail and a div containing text).

## HTML

```
<article class="featured">
  <div class="category">
    <a href="/#/#/">Category name</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/my-img/" class="thumb-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url(http://my-image-path);"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <h2><a href="/#/">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet vehicula erat, eget volutpat erat. In imperdiet ligula id mauris convallis aliquet quis congue dui. Integer vulputate erat augue, ac aliquam velit iaculis at. </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

So there are three child elements of `article`: `div.category`, `a` and `div.text`

I want to make `div.category` sit full width/`max-width:100%` across `article` and I then want `a` and `div.text` to sit next to each other using flex. I've already got this working elsewhere, but not when `div.category` is present.

Here's a little mock-up

[image]

As I said, I don't want to change the HTML structure and I would like to make use of `flex` as this is what I have used elsewhere.

My problem is making `div.category` full width when its parent (`article`) has `display:flex;` applied. Essentially I am trying to overwrite the effect of `flex` on just `div.category`

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zv8hhn1x/3/)

I have tried applying `width:100%` to the category, and then also applying `flex-shrink:0;` so that it cannot be shrunk, but then the second two elements don't wrap onto the next line. And using `flex-wrap` to make them wrap doesn't have them sitting in one row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `flex: 0 0 50%` on `.thumb-wrapper` and `.text`
, and `flex: 0 0 100%` on `.category`, and don't forget to set `flex-wrap: wrap` on `article`

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
article {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.category, .thumb-wrapper, .text {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.category {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.thumb-wrapper, .thumb {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<article class="featured">
  <div class="category">
    <a href="/#/#/">Category name</a>
  </div>
  <a href="/my-img/" class="thumb-wrapper">
    <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('http://placehold.it/350x150');"></div>
  </a>
  <div class="text">
    <h2><a href="/#/">Lorem ipsum</a></h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sit amet vehicula erat, eget volutpat erat. In imperdiet ligula id mauris convallis aliquet quis congue dui. Integer vulputate erat augue, ac aliquam velit iaculis at.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```